# Split within align* environment

Tags: amsmath

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{+a}f(x)e^{-i\frac{n\pi x}{a}}\; dx = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_n\int_{-a}^{+a}e^{i(n-m)\frac{\pi x}{a}}\; dx = \\
\text{for } n \neq m: \quad \int_{-a}^{+a}e^{-i\frac{n\pi x}{a}}\; dx 
\begin{split}
&=  \left[\frac{e^{i(n-m)\frac{\pi x}{a}}}{i(n-m)\frac{\pi}{a}}\right]^{+a}_{-a} = \frac{e^{i(n-m)\pi}-e^{-i(n-m)\pi}}{i(n-m)\frac{\pi}{a}}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-m}-(-1)^{n-m}}{i(n-m)\frac{\pi}{a}} = 0
\end{split}\\
\text{for } n   =  m: \quad \int_{-a}^{+a}e^{-i\frac{n\pi x}{a}}\; dx
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not `\begin{split}`, but `\begin{aligned}[t]`. Remove `\displaystyle` that doesn nothing at all. The space before the differential should be `\,` and not `\;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-a}^{+a}f(x)e^{-i\frac{n\pi x}{a}}\, dx
  = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_n\int_{-a}^{+a}e^{i(n-m)\frac{\pi x}{a}}\, dx\\
&\text{for $n \neq m$:} \quad \int_{-a}^{+a}e^{-i\frac{n\pi x}{a}}\, dx
\begin{aligned}[t]
&=  \left[\frac{e^{i(n-m)\frac{\pi x}{a}}}{i(n-m)\frac{\pi}{a}}\right]^{+a}_{-a} = 
    \frac{e^{i(n-m)\pi}-e^{-i(n-m)\pi}}{i(n-m)\frac{\pi}{a}}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-m}-(-1)^{n-m}}{i(n-m)\frac{\pi}{a}} = 0
\end{aligned}\\
&\text{for $n=m$:} \quad \int_{-a}^{+a}e^{-i\frac{n\pi x}{a}}\, dx = \int_{-a}^a dx = 2a
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The trick is `aligned` with the `[t]` specifier.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the improvements too - all duly noted.